# Get random element from associative array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am building a playlist of songs in javascript. I have used an associative array `foo` -- the structure of my object looks akin to:

```
foo[songID] = songURL;
```

I am trying to build in shuffling functionality. I would like to select a song at random from this list. Is there a simple way to do this -- the array is not indexed.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the function `Object.keys(object)` to get an array of the keys of an object. Very good documentation for this function can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

You also seem to have two different but related questions.

Your topic asks how to get a random element from an object. For that,

```
var randomProperty = function (object) {
  var keys = Object.keys(object);
  return object[keys[Math.floor(keys.length * Math.random())]];
};
```

But you also ask in the body of your question how to shuffle the array. For that, you'll want a [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) function of some sort (most probably an implementation of Fischer-Yates), and do that directly.

```
var objectKeysShuffled = function (object) {
    return shuffle(Object.keys(object));
};
```

Comment: @kennis - That should be IE < 9.

Comment: Hmm, looking back on this, I misread the question. It was asking how to shuffle, and I gave a function for picking a random song... whoops. Main thing to note is that once you have an array with Object.keys, you can shuffle it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the function I made to play a random background song from a hash of audio elements.

```
this.bgm = {} //I later added audio elements to this
this.playRandomBGM = function()
{
    var keys = Object.keys(this.bgm);
    self.currentBGM = keys[Math.floor(keys.length * Math.random())];
    console.log("Playing random BGM: " + self.currentBGM);
    self.bgm[self.currentBGM].play();
}
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like my answer inlined into a function that adds a whole lot of noisy code unrelated to the question. Your fourth and fifth lines are identical to mine, except you replaced `return` with with `self.currentBGM =`, even though there's no `self` or `currentBGM` in the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var obj = {
    'song1': 'http://...1',
    'song2': 'http://...2',
    'song3': 'http://...3',
    'song4': 'http://...4',
    'song5': 'http://...5',
    'song6': 'http://...6',
}, tempArr = [], len, rand, song;

for ( var key in obj )
    if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) )
        tempArr.push( obj[key] );

len = tempArr.length;
rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * len );
song = tempArr[rand];
document.write(song);
```

Note that this is really just a hacky way of skirting around the fact that this stuff should probably be in an array with a structure like this:

```
var songs = [
    {title: 'Song1', url: 'http://...1.mp3'},
    {title: 'Song2', url: 'http://...2.mp3'},
    {title: 'Song3', url: 'http://...3.mp3'}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fetchRandom(arr) {
    var ret,
        i = 0;
    for (var key in arr){
        if (Math.random() < 1/++i){
           ret = key;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

var randomSong = foo[fetchRandom(foo)];
```

You should use an object for this. Then use an indexed array of objects for randomization, but this should answer your question.

Comment: Trivial bug: This will always give the first key because during the first iteration, i === 0, and 1/++i  will always be greater than Math.random().

Comment: Nontrivially, you're computing a different random number for each key. Even if Math.random() was perfectly random, your function cannot possibly give a truly random result. The probability for the `N`th element would be `(N/length)*Product([1, N), N/Length)`, not N/Length.

Answer (score 0):

An inefficient method is:

```
function randomProperty(obj) {
  var a = [];
  for (var p in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      a.push(p);
    }
  }
  return a.length? obj[ a[a.length * Math.random() | 0]] : void 0;
}
```

As others have said, much more efficient store the property name array and re-use it than to make it each time.